# "event js 85 error" while building ionic cordova app

Tags: android, windows, cordova, cmd, ionic-framework

I am having issues building my ionic app. I've installed everything, but I get the issue when I am trying to build my application.

here's an image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this problem with this:

Hope it helps anyone who encountered the same issue.

copy and paste: 
"%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" to your enviroment variables and rebuild everything.